# Could it cause jar hell? Or some other class loader issues

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

Env:tomcat 6
I have one coreTool.jar used in a web project.

For some enhancement in coreTool, I added new class files and save this coreTool to coreToolSec.jar and make both include into the project.

As you can see there would be lots of dublicate classes with same package name, classes name, and I am afraid of doing this may cause system goes wrong.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not add the modifications to just one JAR?

Comment: You said you added *new* class files; why would there be duplicate classnames? Use some common sense when creating new functionality.

Comment: @DaveNewton:  Perhaps the name collisions from the different JAR files?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.  Add new class files to `coreTool.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

> For some enhancement in coreTool, I added new class files and save
>   this coreTool to coreToolSec.jar and make both include into the
>   project.

Why don't you remove the old jar and keep only `coreToolSec.jar` renaming it to `coreTool.jar` and keep only that in your classpath?
There is no reason for a second jar since you are adding new classes to the existing jar.
So you have both old and new classes in the same jar.

Friends here can correct me, but with your way, what will happen is the following:
Jars are loaded according to the order in the classpath, so e.g. the old classes will be loaded by the the classloader first and then they will not be reloaded (since classloader loads each class only once) and then the new classes will be loaded from the latest jar.
But then you will have part of the classes from old jar and part from the new jar.
I am not sure if this will not cause problems.